# Wordpress change the permalink

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

So I am new to WordPress. Now I want to change the permalink settings of my post. Currently, my post URL includes dates like http://siteaddress.com/2019/11/21/topic-of-discussion/. Now I want to remove the date part. 
I googled and found many references which say under your settings, there will be permalink options, but now it is not there.

Also, I read a few places where it says on your post header you can change the permalink address. But here also I am not able to remove the date.

Is there any other way I can do this.

Answer (score 0):

Is your website hosted on Wordpress.com? On this website it says that it is not possible to change that.

See https://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/permalink-settings-configuration-missing/

Comment: Yup. I do not have that button for permalinks. And I have very fewer numbers of options compared to your screenshot

Comment: Is your website hosted on Wordpress.com?

Comment: Yes, it is hoasted on wordpress.com

Comment: So according to the article, I cannot change the permalink settings? Can I use any plugin to do so ?

Comment: Probably not. Functionality is limited on Wordpress.com as you can see here: 
https://en.support.wordpress.com/com-vs-org/

Comment: OK. Thanks for the clarification.